# How to access JSON data field in jQuery-Autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Server response returns following array in JSON format:

```
suggestions[] = array( 'value' => 'test value', 'data' => 'test data' );
```

By default in jQuery-Autocomplete plugin i can access only `value` field from JSON server response (on jquery.autocomplete.js line: 565):

```
html += '<div class="' + className + '" data-index="' + i + '">' + formatResult(suggestion, value) + '</div>';
```

My question is, how could i access `data` field value if it's string, or maybe how could i access `data` values if it's array (in some cases).

Short speaking, i would like to change code to:

```
html +='<div class="' + className + '" data-index="' + i + '">'
html +='<div class="header">' + suggestion.value + '</div>'
html +='<div class="contents">' + suggestion.data + '</div>'
html +='</div>';
```

But i dont get it, how could i access `data` field from server response? Tank you :)

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Your data value is in value.data

try this :

```
$('your_selector').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'your_service',
    minChar: 2,
    onSelect: function(value){console.log(value.data);}
});
```